# Oracle PL/SQL - Way to combine declaration of variables with same type into a single statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

Can you do anything like this in PL/SQL?

```
variableName DataType,
variableName2,
variableName3;
```

You can do this in other languages.

Oracle 9i

Comment: Is there a genuine need to? If so, under what circumstances?

Comment: No need really, just wondering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in PL/SQL you have to declare each variable separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBTYPEs if the aim is to be able to change the definition of lots of variables very easily [eg change address_line_1, address_line_2 etc from VARCHAR2(30) to VARCHAR2(50)]